# Jumbotron de tamaño completo dentro de un container

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3, bootstrap-4

Estoy creando una aplicación de una sola página, que funcionará solo en navegadores y los sub-componentes se cargan dentro del componente principal, mas o menos así:

```
<div class="container">
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Entonces, todos los componentes quedan dentro del `container`, pero no he podido crear un estilo que me permita **ignorar**, *salir* o como sea, de los límites del container.

```css
.parrafo {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

/* no funciona
.jumbotron-dentro {
  margin: -900px
}
*/
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Este código está en el componente principal -->
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="display-3">Mega Jumbotron</h1>
  </div>
</div>
 
 <div class="container"><!-- El container lo pone el componente principal -->
 <!-- A partir de aqui se cargan los subcomponentes -->
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 parrafo">
        <p>
          Este párrafo está contenido por el tamaño del <code>container</code>, 
          para eso le agregué el borde, para que sea visible. 
        </p>
     </div><!-- ./col-md-12 -->
   </div><!-- ./row -->
   
   <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid jumbotron-dentro">
     <div class="container">
       <h1 class="display-3">Otro Mega jumbotron</h1>
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 parrafo">
        <p>
          ¿Es posible que el jumbotron de arriba ocupe todo el espacio
          del viewport, y <strong>que se vea como el primero</strong>.
        </p>
     </div><!-- ./col-md-12 -->
   </div><!-- ./row -->
   
  <!-- ./Aqui termina el sub-componente -->
  </div><!-- ./container -->
```

Encontré esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972305/full-width-image-inside-container-in-bootstrap-4) que me parece bastante lógica, que dice que debería usar un margen negativo del mismo tamaño que la elemento padre, entonces he tratado con fragmentos como el siguiente:

```
/* no funciona */
.jumbotron-dentro {
  margin: -900px
}
```

pero mis intentos no han rendido frutos.

¿Es posible que una elemento, por ejemplo, una `div`, ocupe todo el espacio del *viewport*, aunque el elemento padre tenga un ancho fijo menor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estoy seguro de lo que quieres realmente, pero por lo que puedo entender es que quieres dar un estilo que asigna a un elemento el ancho y alto de la pantalla. Para ello:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
}
```

Y para el elemento hijo:

```
.hijo {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Gracias, no conocía esa nueva característica.